# Create nested dictionary with loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to build the nested function looks like this.

```
test = {}
test[0] = {}
test[0][1] = {}
test[0][1][2] = {}
test
```

result

```
{0: {1: {2: {}}}}
```

Is there any way to create one with for loop?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try building the dict starting from the inner most part:

```py
output = {}
for x in [2, 1, 0]:
    output = {x: output}

print(output) # {0: {1: {2: {}}}}
```

To build it from the outer most layer, you can consider a temporary "pointer" for sub-dicts:

```py
output = subdict = {}

for x in [0, 1, 2]:
    subdict[x] = {}
    subdict = subdict[x]

print(output) # {0: {1: {2: {}}}}
```

Or using recursion:

```py
def build_dict(keys):
    if not keys:
        return {}
    return {keys[0]: build_dict(keys[1:])}

print(build_dict([0, 1, 2])) # {0: {1: {2: {}}}}
```

Comment: On the other hand, Is there anyway to build it from the outer most part?

Comment: Thanks! This solves out the problem that I couldn't fix it for a hour. Thousand blessing on you!